# What is a good approach for Database design for hours of operation?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am trying to create an application that will need to use hours of operation and allow users to search by it (think how Yelp does this).

I am debating what is a good design for this.  The only thing I can think of is having a database table with a foreign key to a "Companies" table that lists a day of the week and the open and close times.

```
Tbl_Hours_Operation
- day_of_week
- open_time
- close_time
- company_id
```

Is there any other approach that would work and be more efficient?

Comment: Seems good so far... what about holidays?

Comment: No one gets holidays off.  Problem solved!

Comment: It sounds like you'd want to have a fairly closed set of "standard hours" which you've designed, and then you'd want to have an additional more often-changing set of "exceptions" to cover things like holiday hours, per-location changes to hours, etc.

Comment: You also need to allow multiple entries for the day_of_week/company_id pair to handle businesses that close for a period during the day.  Very common in some countries.

Answer (score 10):

Have two tables:

**operational_hours** (company_id, day_of_week, open_time, close_time)

**operational_hours_special** (company_id, date, open_time, close_time)

You would need to join the two tables to check for the special hours.

Will any of your companies be closed for breakfast, lunch, dinner, [siesta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siesta)? If so, I would add:

**operational_hours_closed** (company_id, day_of_week, close_time, open_time)

Even more fun `JOIN`s!

Comment: For the closed for lunch, the same may be accomplished by allowing a company to have multiple entries per `day_of_week` in the `operational_hours` table.  So instead of a join with a set of closed hours, just two records of open hours.

Comment: And you could pretty easily build a view on top of that which would give you the correct hours for any arbitrary date.

Comment: @David My personal preference for having explicit closed hours would be to identify the specific reason for being closed.

Comment: ...Granted, this may all be overkill given the OP's description ("Think how Yelp does this), as they may be interested in storing a fixed set of regular hours of operation per company, and not in being able to determine whether or not a company was open at any historical point in time. But that's the trouble with these high-level design questions. :)

Comment: -1: beautiful academic solution, horrible pratical solution. Imagine that he has about 1000 stores that opens every regular day from 9 to 5. That would result in 7000 records that would have to be matched for joins... Academic solutions do look nice, but it results in costly solutions that have a bad cost-effectiveness balance...

Comment: @Leonardo: Unless he's running this on a calculator, 7,000 records probably isn't going to be a problem.  Relational databases are _very_ good at optimizing execution paths.  There's a big difference between how one stores the data and how one answers questions about the data.  The former needs to accommodate the latter, but shouldn't be tightly coupled to it.  As for cost effectiveness, I really don't see how a bad design is going to reduce costs.  Good design isn't "academic," it is in every way practical.

Comment: @Leonardo Could you please elaborate how this is a horrible practical solution and offer a better solution? I'm still very confused by what you mean by *academic*. If you are referring to a "by-the-book" solution, the solution you proposed below is neither "by-the-book" or "practical."

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems sound.  Just a few minor things to note:

Make sure you index this table on Company_Id and DayOfWeek_Id (and in that order).  It should also (possibly) support multiple entries per day of week, in case the company closes during the day or if it is open overnight.

```
CompanyDayOfWeek
----------------
Company_Id     INT/BIGINT    FK->Company table
DayOfWeek_Id   INT           (this can be a FK or just a hard coded list of IDs)
Open_Time      TIME          if your DB supports a dateless time data type
Close_Time     TIME
```